# Try to launch an application from another application continue to crash

Tags: c#, process, exec

I wrote a program in C # that takes, from a WPF interface, a folder path, a prefix, and a prefix of substitution. The purpose of the program is to search in the folder all the files that start with the prefix and rename them with the new prefix. This program works without any problems.

Now I have to write a second program that must call the previous, passing the parameters using args []. I wrote this second program, it seems that all the parameters have passed correctly to the other (I checked it), but every time the replacement program runs out after a few seconds (while the normal run in my folder of Trial is almost instantly). I'm not able to have any message error or exception, I can only obtain the windows alert message that reports the crash.

Here is the significant part of the code of both programs ... Can anyone help me to find the problem? Is it a problem with settings passed from one program to another? Thanks a lot to everyone.

Can it maybe be a problem about the setting parameters of the calling?

Replace prefix program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.IO;

namespace replace_prefix
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string[] args;
            args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            if (args.Length > 1)
            {
                ((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).Close();
                sf_textBox.Text = args[1];
                rp_textBox.Text = args[2];
                np_textBox.Text = args[2];
                replace();
            }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ok_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            replace();
        }

        private void replace() {
            if (sf_textBox.Text == "" || rp_textBox.Text == "" || np_textBox.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Insert all required parameters", "Parameter missing", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = File.CreateText("log.txt"))
                {

                    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(sf_textBox.Text);
                    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.*");
                    string filename, log;
                    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
                    {
                        filename = file.Name;
                        int Place = filename.IndexOf(rp_textBox.Text);
                        if (Place == 0)
                        {
                            log = "file " + filename + " renamed ";
                            filename = filename.Remove(Place, rp_textBox.Text.Length).Insert(Place, np_textBox.Text);
                            file.MoveTo(file.Directory.FullName + "\\" + filename);
                            Log(log + filename, w);
                        }
                    }
                    w.Close();
                }
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
        {
            w.Write(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.Write(" --> ");
            w.WriteLine(logMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling method in the other program:

```
        public void LaunchCommandLineApp()
        {
            using (StreamWriter wl = File.CreateText(job.name + "_log.txt"))
            {
                lock (wl) wl.WriteLine("\\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " --> " + job.name + ": " + job.process + " launched");
                // Use ProcessStartInfo class
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.FileName = job.process;
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                var count = job.args.Count(c => c == ';');
                startInfo.Arguments = "";// "-f ";
                while (count > 1)
                {
                    startInfo.Arguments += job.args.Substring(0, job.args.IndexOf(';', 0));
                    int i = job.args.IndexOf(';', 0) + 1, k = job.args.Length - 1;
                    job.args = job.args.Substring((job.args.IndexOf(';', 0) + 1), (job.args.Length - 1) - (job.args.IndexOf(';', 0)));
                    count--;
                }
                if (count == 1) {
                    int i = job.args.IndexOf(';', 0);
                    startInfo.Arguments += job.args.Substring(0, job.args.IndexOf(';', 0)); 

                }

                if (job.recurrency) job.updateRecurrency();

                try
                {
                    // Start the process with the info we specified.
                    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
                    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                    {
                        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                        string tl;
                        try
                        {
                            tl = Path.GetDirectoryName(job.process);
                        }
                        catch (ArgumentException e) {
                            tl = null;
                        }
                        if (tl != null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                tl = tl + "\\log.txt";
                                StreamReader input = new StreamReader(tl);
                                tl = input.ReadLine();
                                while (tl != null)
                                {
                                    wl.WriteLine(tl);
                                    tl = input.ReadLine();
                                }
                                input.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) { }
                        }
                        lock (wl) wl.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " --> " + job.name + ": " + job.process + " successfully ended.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //add local process log
                    lock (wl) wl.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " --> " + job.name + ": " + job.process + " failed to ended. " + e.Message.ToString());
                }

                wl.Close();
                InvokeExecutionFinished(new EventArgs());
            }

            //Send log via email
            //sendNotification();

        }
```

[Crash report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok1Nq.jpg)

Comment: `I can only obtain the windows alert message that reports the crash.` Can you share that with us?

Comment: I've added a link to it at the end of the code

Comment: Its hard to tell what is wrong from your code, but have noticed you are using args[2] twice in the WPF app when you put the args into the text boxes, could that be the problem?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a mistake but no, i'm sure thats not the problem. (That mistake only set a match between the research prefix with the replace one). I know it's hard. My problem is exactly that. I'm unable to obtain sufficient information to know where the problem could be...

Comment: If i was you I would move the code that does the renaming (so the replace method) into a class library, then call that code from the WPF app and the second program. You can then debug etc.